# Postgraphile change field case in schema

Tags: graphql, postgraphile

Is there any way to make all the fields in `postgraphile` schema lowercase even if the database fields are camelCased (i.e `customerName` => `customername`)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done using an *InflectionPlugin*. Find out more about inflection [here](https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/inflection/). You will have to dig the documentation and the source code a bit but with some trail and error you should get there pretty quickly.